# How can i resolve this error in below code?

Tags: java

How can I resolve this error?

> error: ';' expected
>
> boolean isAmazing(int checkNum,counter){
>                        ^
>   error: ';' expected
>
> boolean isAmazing(int checkNum,counter){

THIS IS THE METHOD IN WHICH I AM GETTING THE ERROR :

```
boolean isAmazing(int checkNum,counter){
    for(int i=1;i<=checkNum/2;i++){
        if(checkNum/i==0){
            counter++;
            if(counter>2){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: WHY DO YOU SCREAM? And please, please, PLEASE fix your code indentation. http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Comment: Put `int` before `counter` in the method declaration

Comment: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

On the first line of your method, you have:
 
**boolean isAmazing(int checkNum, counter){**

The counter variable has no type associated with it. it should look more like this:

**boolean isAmazing(int checkNum, int counter){**

Putting that together and being properly formatted should look more like the following:

```
boolean isAmazing(int checkNum, int counter){
    for(int i = 1; i <= checkNum/2; i++){
        if(checkNum/i==0){
            counter++;
            if(counter>2){
                return false;
            }
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```

Java is a strongly typed language, meaning that all variables have to have a type and can not change that type.

Comment: after declaring counter variable still the error is same.

Comment: @Khushi Can you show me the code where you call the method?

Comment: @Khushi I have verified the function in testing. there is nothing wrong with the one that I have posted and works fine without fail. Which says that you are missing a semicolon before you make this call or when you make this call. Sometimes the compiler will tell you a line of code is an error but its actually the right before it. make sure you have semicolons before you make this call and where you make this call.

Comment: public static void main (String[] args) {
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
     int number=scan.nextInt();
     int count=0;
     boolean br=isAmazing(number,count);
     if(br)
         System.out.println(1);
     else
         System.out.println(0);
     
 boolean isAmazing(int checkNum,int counter){
         for(int i=1;i<=checkNum/2;i++){
             if(checkNum/i==0){
                 counter++;
                 if(counter>2){
                     return false;
                 }
             }
             
         }
         return true;
     }
    }
}

Comment: you can not declare a method inside of a method . You need to move it outside of the main method.

Comment: No problem. If your issue is solved please accept the answer to let people know the question is resolved.

Comment: Also, please do not post code in comments. Can YOU read that?

Comment: True. I had to copy and paste the code, then format it to read it. It was a bit of a pain.